# How can I create different Nomenclature lists for each chapter?

Tags: nomenclature, nomencl

I am writing my PhD Thesis, which has several chapters. I want to create different nomenclatures for each chapter like this:
Chapter 3
Nomenclature of Chapter 3

Chapter 4
Nomenclature of Chapter 4
...
 I tried to put all the `\nomenclature{..}{..}` and `\printnomenclature` in each chapter, but it displays all my variables from my thesis, instead of only of the specific chapter.

How can I print only the variables I want for the chapter?

Comment: `nomencl` does not support multiple files. All `\nomenclature` usages enter the regular file and are stored 'globally', so you see the whole nine yards with `\printnomenclature. There might be a trick, however, by changing the file handle that is used. Please provide a compilable document that shows your issue (I don't want to setup such file for myself)

Comment: Looking into the `glossaries` package (both the package documentation and related questions here) might be useful, if changing packages is acceptable for you.